# <inset> with a <bitmap> as its child not work

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Here is drawable xml:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:padding="15dp">
           <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_laucher"/>
</inset>
```

The file above could work well on My XT-1032(5.1.1),but not work well on other phones.

When I use it with a ImageView, a red exclamation mark will appear on the left,but there is no hint about it.

[image]

Here is its bounds on the other phones:
[image]